# Products not display in other languages

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n, panels, multi-sites

I am using multi-language [internationalize](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module for category and products translate. When product created assigning only English language category only but not assign other languages, How to assign to other languages.

There is any solution for this with module or else any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

check the (http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module   and also read this  https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/820/how-do-i-setup-multilingual-products

https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/translation